# Understanding how to use Indexing

Tags: python, indexing

Looking for better clarification on how to achieve the following instructions.

> ```
> # loop while i is less than the length of name and the i-th character is not a space.
> # return the part of name up to but not including the i-th character to the caller.
> ```

```
def get_first_name(name):
    i = 0
    while i < len(name) and '' in str(i):
        i += 1
    return name
```

Comment: The *"i-th character"* is the character at the index `i`, i.e. `name[i]`. Note that iterating over Python strings by index is usually unnecessary - you could do `for char in name:` to get each character instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not implementing your function, but just explaining the logic as I believe this the part of your some exercise.

Your condition could be written as:

```
name = "Hello World"
i = 0

# len(name): will return the length of `name` string
# name[i] != " ": will check that item at `i`th position is not blank space

while i < len(name) and name[i] != " ":
    print name[:i+1]  # print string from start to the `i`th position
    i += 1
```

which will print:

```
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
```

Now, I guess you know how to put this logic in your function and which value to return ;)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it helped me understand the questions better.

Comment: I am glad to know that I help the person asking the question to know his question better. Just kidding :D  I know by question you meant your assignment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Python are sequences, which you can index using notation like `name[i]`. Therefore you can loop through the string letter by letter, and keep comparing to a space character `' '`. Each time you hit a letter that is not a space, append it to your temporary string. Once you hit a white space, stop looping, and the value of your temporary string will represent their first name.

```
def get_first_name(name):
    first = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(name) and name[i] != ' ':
        first += name[i]  # append this letter
        i += 1            # increment the index
    return first
```

Example

```
>>> get_first_name('John Jones')
'John'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the advice, using them I have been able to get my code working to the specification I required.

```
   # Function designed to retrieve first name only from fullname entry.
def get_first_name(name):
    i = 0 
    while i < len(name) and name[i] !=" ":
        i += 1
    return name[:i]

# Function designed to retrieve first initial of last name or first initial of first name if only one name input.
def get_last_initial(name):
    j = len(name) - 1 
    while j >= 0 and name[j] !=" ":
        j-=1
    return full_name[j+1]

# Function that generates username based upon user input.
def get_username(full_name):
    username = get_first_name(full_name) + get_last_initial(full_name) 
    return username.lower()
```